# Use hashtag inside the_post_thumbnail() attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am creating **Bootstrap Modal** appear dynamically on the basis of **Thumbnail ID** in my WordPress site. However, I need to use `hashtag` **#** tag inside the `the_post_thumbnail()` attribute. It comments the attribute data instead. My question is

> Is there a trick to insert `# tag` inside **`PHP`** variable ?

**Here's my code :**

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    #var_dump($post_thumbnail_id);
    the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-thumb', array( 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); } 
?>
```

in the attribute, `'data-target' => get_post_thumbnail_id()`, I want to display it as `'data-target' => #get_post_thumbnail_id()`

Each `data-target` has unique `ID`, that's why I need the **hash tag**. But I wonder if there's any trick for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried appending # before get_post_thumbnail_id(); ?

Comment: I haven't used jQuery. I have no idea whether we can append the tags before get_post_thumbnail_id(); function using jQuery. Can you help me please?

Comment: 'data-target' => "#".get_post_thumbnail_id() - can it be worked please check ?

Comment: wow, thanx.. it worked.. I didn't thought of it!! Can you post this answer as a solution so that I can approve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **append the #** in you data-target  with function.

Try below code :

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    #var_dump($post_thumbnail_id);
    the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-thumb', array( 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "#".get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate.. Worked !!

Comment: yeah keep helping :)